# Best way to build a checkbox or radio button to be able to be referenced in a Java Script function?

Tags: javascript, html

Im pretty new to html and I am building a webpage in html for work. It is basically a list of standards that a reviewer goes over and determines if a plan given to him/her meets those standards. I need to have either a checkbox(s) or radio button for "Accepted" and "Incomplete", but I need to be able to reference them later on with Java Script to run a report for the reviewer. Whats the best way to do this and should I use check boxes or radio buttons? I have my code attached, I am basically creating a bunch of rows in the table

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td> <!--standard number--></td>
        <td><!--standard name--></td>
        <td> <input type="checkbox"> </td> <!--accepted checkbox-->
        <td> <input type="checkbox"> </td> <!--incomplete checkbox-->
        <td> <input type="text"> </td> <!--comments field-->
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Javascript can reference both radio buttons and checkboxes. It depends on your requirement what to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome and Thanks for asking the question.

So the difference between checkbox and radio button is with checkbox you can select as many as you want (e.g. Red/Green/Yellow/Blue) and with radio button you have a group where you select only one (e.g. Yes/No)

I created a fiddle with your example to show you how to access those elements: https://jsfiddle.net/vrjzfyun/

```
var accepted = document.querySelector("#cbAccepted");
accepted.checked = true;
```

Let us know if you have more questions.

Comment: You're welcome. Please remember to mark it as the answer if it indeed helped you solve your question.